# Raspberry Pi 4 as WiFi extender causes audio problems on Windows 10 when connected

Tags: wifi, audio, windows

After following tutorial provided in [this answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/89804/125837) i've managed to use my Raspberry Pi 4 as WiFi extender and it's working really good. The main and only problem is that when i'm connected on my PC with Windows 10 to that network my audio (on that PC) starts to stutter (like a lot and very often). When i change to any other network - stuttering stops and audio is as smooth as it was before connecting to that network.

I've already tried to:

- reinstall NIC drivers on PC with Windows 10
- reboot both devices
- use headphones instead of my speakers (to check if it's my speakers/their driver fault but it isn't)

but nothing helped.

My NIC: Edimax EW-7612Pin.

Edit:
Just noticed that whole PC stutters (video and audio and everything) not just audio.

Comment: Do you use the downgraded [firmware-brcm80211_20190114-1+rpt4_all.deb](http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/pool/main/f/firmware-nonfree/), or do you use the default firmware coming with the Raspberry Pi OS? How do you connect to any other network? Direct to the local main router, or is there also an additional repeater used?

Comment: Yes I use downgraded firmware and i connect directly to the main router which is connected to the main network of the provider.

Comment: try with `wmm_enabled=1` instead of `wmm_enabled=0` in hostapd.conf (I'm assuming you are streaming audio over the connection to the pi)

Comment: It has been reported that network adapters on Windows  sometimes interrupts the audio adapter. In those cases, reinstalling the Windows network driver helps. This may be caused by the fact that the Pi may be slower in certain parts of the protocol than your other network.

Comment: @JaromandaX I'm not streaming audio over the connection to the pi but i'll give it a try.

Comment: in that case it won't matter ... the pi has nothing to do with the issue ... try a different wifi adapter on the PC

Comment: @LjmDullaart reinstalled both network and audio driver and i can see some improvement, but it still happens sometimes...

Comment: @JaromandaX It has to do with the issue. If i'm connected to any other network the audio plays smoothly

Comment: I believe you @Feralnex - despite the fact that sounds unbelievable!! Nobody would make that up!!!

Comment: What audio source do you use? From the internet? How do you play audio on the PC?  From within the internet browser? Or do you use any other application?

Comment: @Ingo audio source doesn't matter anymore. PC just starts to stutter when i'm connected to rpi network (it's milliseconds so it's hard to notice, but when i'm listening to music i can 'hear' it). It's happening on my PCIe WiFi card, but when i'm using USB WiFi adapter everything is ok.